# Issues with in app-purchases. The name 'DependencyService' does not exist in the current

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I try how to implement consumable in-app purchases in my project.

Tutorials:

[Purchase consumable](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/PurchaseConsumable.html)

[Securing in-app purchases](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/SecuringPurchases.html)

I have read these tutorials but I don't know what DependencyService, Debug and Device is. I get the following error messages:

> Error CS0103: The name 'DependencyService' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)
>   Error CS0103: The name 'Device' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)
>   Error CS0103: The name 'Debug' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)

In addition, I don't understand what this line of code means. Why are we checking Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? What should I do if it is true and what should I do when it is false?

```
 if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            return;
```

This is how I implemented the code to my project:

```
 string payload = "apppayload";
    public async Task<bool> PurchaseItem(string productId, string payload)
    {
        if (!CrossInAppBilling.IsSupported)
            return false;

        var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
        try
        {
            var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);
            if (!connected)
            {
                //we are offline or can't connect, don't try to purchase
                return false;
            }

            var verify = DependencyService.Get<IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase>();

            //check purchases
            var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, payload, verify);

            //possibility that a null came through.
            if (purchase == null)
            {
                //did not purchase
            }
            else if (purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
            {
                //purchased, we can now consume the item or do it later

                //If we are on iOS we are done, else try to consume the purchase
                //Device.RuntimePlatform comes from Xamarin.Forms, you can also use a conditional flag or the DeviceInfo plugin
                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                    return false;

                var consumedItem = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConsumePurchaseAsync(purchase.ProductId, purchase.PurchaseToken);

                if (consumedItem != null)
                {
                    //Consumed!!
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
        {
            //Billing Exception handle this based on the type
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + purchaseEx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Something else has gone wrong, log it
            Debug.WriteLine("Issue connecting: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            await billing.DisconnectAsync();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mh... "DependencyService" and "Device" are subClasses of Xamarin.Forms, so if you haven't already do that add:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
```

on top of your code

If DependencyService/Debug still not exist i think you're in the wrong project, you need to use it in your "portable" project, and not in OS-Related projects.
Try to study how [Cross-Platform xamarin projects works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/) :)

Legion-

Comment: Thank you. But I still get the error message for Debug. Error CS0103: The name 'Debug' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (PurchaseTest.iOS)

Comment: I added using System.Diagnostics; to my project and that fixed the error message.

Comment: Exactly, Same error as above, sorry i forgot to answer to the last point :)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine

Comment: Do you know what this line means? if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS) I don't understand why I need to check that. Can I just call the next line( var consumedItem = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConsumePurchaseAsync(purchase.ProductId, purchase.PurchaseToken);)  if (Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.iOS)?

Comment: It depends if you're only coding for IOS or you're coding multi-platform application.
If you've a shared code ios/android you need to test if you're under IOS before launch your piece of code that is ios specific :)

Comment: Thanks, now I have understand it. Right now, I'm only coding for iOS, but I will try to do a shared code iOS/Android project in a few weeks.